# XSD with separated complex types using targetNamespace

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-namespaces, xml-validation

I wrote a very simple XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<something attribute1="21" attribute2="23">
  <newelement code="code1"/>
</something>
```

And I wanted to write an XSD to validate this XML, which works perfectly:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="something">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="newelement" nillable="true">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="code"/>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="attribute1" type="xs:int"/>
            <xs:attribute name="attribute2" type="xs:int"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

But then I wanted to write the same XSD, but with **separated complex types**, because for example, what if I will need that same structure as the `newelement` has now. So I refactored my XSD this way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema targetNamespace="my-common-types"
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns:tns="my-common-types">
    <xs:element name="something">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="newelement" nillable="true" type="tns:ElementWithCode"/>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="attribute1" type="xs:int"/>
            <xs:attribute name="attribute2" type="xs:int"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:complexType name="ElementWithCode">
        <xs:attribute name="code" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

And then, I always get this error:

> ERROR: Element 'something': No matching global declaration available
>   for the validation root.

So there is a problem using `targetNamespace` attribute on the scheme, but I don't get it how could I make this working. Please give me some advises. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were missing parts from both XML and XSD.

XML was missing the `xmlns="my-common-types"` attribute from the `<something>` element.

XSD was missing the `elementFormDefault="qualified"` attribute from `<xs:schema>` element.

Answer (score 1):

Your refactored schema is for namespace "my-common-types" whereas the original was for no namespace. If you want your elements to be in no namespace, then the (global) element declarations must be in a schema document that has no `targetNamespace`. You can still put the type declarations in a namespace if you want, but they will then have to be in a separate schema document that is imported into the no-namespace schema document using `xs:import`.

Comment: so then how could I define and use the complex types separately, but from the same schema file? can you give me an example?

Comment: I don't understand your problem, sorry.